# How do I search for a specific function name in all my files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I can use CTRL+P to find the file, and then use CTRL+SHIFT+O to find the needed function.

However, if I do not recall where that function is, or just want to save time, is there a way to search ALL functions in ALL files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search a method name across all files you can use CTRL + P and then start search with #.

Press Ctrl+T to searches across files, not just the current file.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how good language support is for the language you're using and given the language support extension you're using for it is, you can use the `Go To Symbol in Workspace...` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), which is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. That would get you do the "origin"/"definition" of the symbol.

If that fails, you can try doing text searches using the Search View (open the Search View, or use the `Search: Find in Files` command).